# How to deploy an application to multiple websites in Azure?

Tags: azure, deployment, web-deployment, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy one web application to multiple websites/instances on Azure. I currently have two VMs running. One as a web server and one as a database server. The nature of the application requires that each client have their own database and as a result their own website for example:

client1.myapplication.com 
client2.myapplication.com 
client3.myapplication.com

I currently have around 15 websites that right now have to be updated manually each time I do a release. I'm looking for a way to automate the release so that all the websites and databases will be updated. All the documentation I am finding on automating releases seem to only deal with one production site and maybe a staging site. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to stick with using an Azure VM for the web application hosting? I ask because using Azure Web Apps would simplify this for you a great deal. You would be able to use "deploy from source control" to deploy a single code base to as many Web Apps as you would like. This would obviate the need for a separate continuous integration server. Let me know and, if that is an option, I will type up an answer for you.

Comment: Unfortunately right now I have to stick with the Azure VM. My application requires installing extra stuff on the server. I'm looking to hopefully get rid of this stuff so I could use the web apps in the future. If you could provide a solution for both that would be fantastic as eventually I think I could migrate my solution in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need a continuous integration server. You can use TFS, TeamCity, Jenkins, etc...

Here's an article showing how to publish with teamcity.
http://www.mikevalenty.com/automatic-deployment-from-teamcity-using-webdeploy/

Comment: Thanks, I feel like I'm moving in the right direction, but I was hoping for an example of setting up a similar environment in regards to the multiple websites.